# Is there a more idiomatic way to split a std::vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, idioms

I've written a function that splits a vector of size N into chunks of not more than size M.

So given a vector of size 47, and chunk size of 10, we get 5 chunks of size: 10,10,10,10,7.

```
template<typename T> std::vector<std::vector<T>> chunkVector(typename std::vector<T> source, typename std::vector<T>::size_type chunkSize)
{
    typename std::vector<std::vector<T>> returnVector;

    for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < source.size(); i += chunkSize) {

        typename std::vector<T>::iterator start = source.begin() + i;
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator end = start + chunkSize > source.end() ? source.end() : start + chunkSize;
        typename std::vector<T> tempVector(start, end);

        returnVector.push_back(tempVector);
    }
    return returnVector;
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?  The requirement of random_access iterators suggests to me there might be a nicer way.

Comment: You should be passing the first argument by const reference.

Comment: Actually @PaulMcKenzie, if you're worried about performance, it's probably best if he just template on the entire type, rather than `std::vector<T>`, then use perfect forwarding.

Comment: @JohnCarter, this solution looks more or less ok.  I can't immediately think of any better solution.  Thought I would suggest making the `?:` operator more verbose (split into a real if statement) just so it's a bit clearer.

Comment: There's a few superfluous `typename`s in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing I would do differently is how to iterate, and how we're appending onto the result vector:

```
template<typename T> 
std::vector<std::vector<T>> chunkVector(const std::vector<T>& source, size_t chunkSize)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
    result.reserve((source.size() + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize);

    auto start = source.begin();
    auto end = source.end();

    while (start != end) {
        auto next = std::distance(start, end) >= chunkSize
                    ? start + chunkSize
                    : end;

        result.emplace_back(start, next);
        start = next;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd add `result.reserve(source.size() / chunkSize+1);`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yep, done. Except slightly different expression.

Comment: Nice C++11 approach.  I always forget about std::distance as well.